# Re-opening a question migrated from another site should change its status as it was before closing it

Tags: feature-request, migrated-questions, reopened-questions

When a question migrated from another site is closed in the receiving site, some operations are performed:

- The question is closed, and locked
- Its answers are locked, and deleted

Re-opening the question just re-opens the question, but the question still needs to be unlocked, and its answers need to be unlocked, and undeleted.

Re-opening the question should automatically do the other two operations automatically. Clearly, that should not be done for answers that were already deleted (or deleted and locked) before the question was closed.